# JavaConfiguration for Spring 4.0 + Security 3.2 + j_spring_security_check

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

1. Create a login page

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
           <title>Test</title>
           <script src="static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
           <script src="static/js/app-controller.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
           <div>Login</div>
           <form name="f" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"/>" method="POST">
               <label for="password">Username</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username"><br/>
               <label for="password">Password</label>&nbsp;<input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password"><br/>
               <input type="submit" value="Validate">&nbsp;<input name="reset" type="reset">
               <input type="hidden" id="${_csrf.parameterName}" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
           </form>
           <hr/>
           <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
               <div>
                   Failed to login.
                   <c:if test="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION != null}">
                     Reason: <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
                   </c:if>
               </div>
           </c:if>
           <hr/>
           <input type="button" value="Echo" id="echo" name="echo" onclick="AppController.echo();">
           <div id="echoContainer"></div>

       </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Declare a WebSecurityConfigurer **HERE IS WHERE I WAS MISSING j_username AND j_password**

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sample.init.security"})
   public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

       @Inject
       private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

       @Inject
       public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
           auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
       }

       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
               .authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers(
                           "/resources/**", 
                           "/static/**", 
                           "/j_spring_security_check", 
                           "/AppController/echo.html").permitAll()
                   .anyRequest().authenticated()
                   .and()
               .formLogin()
                   .usernameParameter("j_username") /* BY DEFAULT IS username!!! */
                   .passwordParameter("j_password") /* BY DEFAULT IS password!!! */
                   .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                   .loginPage("/")
                   .defaultSuccessUrl("/page")
                   .permitAll()
                   .and()
               .logout()
                   .permitAll();
       }

       @Override
       public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
           web
               .ignoring()
                   .antMatchers("/static/**");
       }

   }
   ```
3. Declare a WebMvcConfigurer

   ```
   @EnableWebMvc
   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
           "com.app.controller",        
           "com.app.service",
           "com.app.dao"
   })
   public class WebMvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

       @Bean
       public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
           InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
           viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
           viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
           return viewResolver;
       }

       @Override
       public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addViewController("/page").setViewName("page");
       }

       @Override
       public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
           registry.addResourceHandler("static/**").addResourceLocations("static/");
       }

   }
   ```
4. Declare a Security Initializer

   ```
   public class SecurityWebAppInitializer 
       extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer { }
   ```
5. Declare an App Initialzer

   ```
   public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer  {

       @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {       
           return new Class<?>[]{WebSecurityConfigurer.class};
       }

       @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
           return new Class<?>[]{WebMvcConfigurer.class, DataSourceConfigurer.class};
       }

       @Override
       protected String[] getServletMappings() {
           return new String[]{"/"};
       }

   }
   ```
6. Implement your custom Authentication Provider

   ```
   @Component
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.app.service"})
   public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

       private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);

       @Inject
       private AppService service;

       @Override
       public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

           //Thread.dumpStack();
           String username = authentication.getName();
           String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

           String message = String.format("Username: '%s' Password: '%s'", username, password);
           UserBean userBean = service.validate(username, password);       
           LOG.debug(message);
           if (userBean != null) {
               List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
               grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
               return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userBean, authentication, grantedAuths); 
           } else {
               String error = String.format("Invalid credentials [%s]", message);
               throw new BadCredentialsException(error);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
           return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
       }

   }
   ```

I am skipping EchoController, AppService, AppDao and UserBean.

Thanks.

Comment: @zeh: what does your authentication parameter looks like on method authenticate? What are its properties values?

Comment: @vincentks Both credentials and principal are empty. Checking in the firebug network console, both parameters are dispatched. It looks like they are lost at some point. As I am using the new Spring features (Java Configuration) maybe the Spring Security searchs for another parameter pair names (not j_username nor j_password), I am guessing.

Comment: I just added a controller bypassing validation with an echo method, carring username and password, and they are empty as well using @RequestParam

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In 3.2 version post parameters have changed from j_username to username and j_password to password. The login url has also changed from /j_spring_security_check to /login.

See this link for the explanation of why this change was implemented: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity. These are the changes:

- GET /login renders the login page instead of /spring_security_login
- POST /login authenticates the user instead of /j_spring_security_check
- The username parameter defaults to username instead of j_username
- The password parameter defaults to password instead of j_password

And this for an example of a login form:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form

Comment: i'm using 3.2-RC2 and j_username and j_password are still working... did they changed param and url name from RC2?

Comment: @pasemes Indeed! I just came here to update the code. I found this here http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html But as you mentioned before, point for you, thanks.