# Controller part of Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have created a custom authentication service for spring-security by implementing the interface UserDetailsService, which is refereed in a security-context.xml as a bean so it will be loaded when application starts. Currently the situation is, I have a LoginController with mapping to bean, a service which calls a method in DAO for checking if the username and password is correct. I just don't know what should come under controller. I am posting the code below. Kindly let me know what am I missing in controller. Thank you for your time.

LoginController.java :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class LoginController {

    @Resource(name="userDetailsService")
    private LoginService loginService;

}
```

LoginService.java

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
@RequestMapping("")
public class LoginService implements UserDetailsService{


    @Autowired private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            UserDetails userDetails = null;
            User user = userDao.findByName(username);
            if(user == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");} 
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(user);
    }
}
```

Security-applicationContext.xml

```
  <import resource="servlet-context.xml" />

    <!-- Global Security settings -->
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />


    <!-- Spring Security framework settings -->
    <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" access-denied-page="/403" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="3" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
        </security:session-management>
        <security:form-login login-page="/users" default-target-url="/users" always-use-default-target="true"
                             authentication-failure-url="/denied" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?out=1" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" requires-channel="any" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url requires-channel="any" pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="any" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    </security:http>
    <!-- queries to be run on data -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" >
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Servlet-context.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <!-- beans start here -->
    <beans:bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.WirTauschen"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Login form HTML code

```
**<form id="form" action="<c:url value='/login'/>" method="POST">
                            <div class="box-wrapper">
                                <h4>LOGIN</h4>

                                <div class="iconic-input">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="j_username" value="">
                                    <i class="icons icon-user-3"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="iconic-input">
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="j_password" value="">
                                    <i class="icons icon-lock"></i>
                                </div>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="loginremember"> <label for="loginremember">Remember me</label>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="orange" value="Login">
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="#">Forgot your username?</a>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                                <br class="clearfix">
                            </div>
                            <div class="footer">
                                <h4 class="pull-left">NEW CUSTOMER?</h4>
                                <a class="button pull-right" href="create_an_account.html">Create an account</a>
                            </div>
                             </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icons icon-lock"></i> Create an Account</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: you dont have to configure login controller or login page on your own. Please try to remove LoginController. Spring security should automatically provide login form on /login page ( if its version 3.2 or above ) .

Comment: @freakman : Thanks man. I have SpringSecurity 3.2.5. One question, What do you mean by I dont need a login page of my own, I have integrated code in above HTML page. If for action I use the tag 'j_spring_security_check'(something similar), the apache tries to redirect page to something different which the browser cant process and application stops working. That is why I was designing a controller.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704656/javaconfiguration-for-spring-4-0-security-3-2-j-spring-security-check . Im not sure now, but probably Spring security provides login form for you, by default its on /login path. If you need to provide your own template, then configure it using <form-login> tag with "username" and "password" fields in form itself which posts on /login

Comment: @freakman : Thanks, I was missing a slash.. :-(, but there are comments on the forum which say, that now Spring uses /login as /j_spring_security_check. One last thing, I dont have the class public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  in my code. Do I need it?

Comment: no, you would have to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter when configuring spring security in java ( which I recommend ). You can always switch to it when your xml version is working : ) And /j_spring_security_check was changed to /login - not the other way.

Comment: I am confused a bit, Do I need all the 3 things, Like an app initailizer mentioned, a class which implements AuthenticationManager(I have already implemented UserDetailsService) and a WebMVCConfigurer?

Comment: As all this stuff is declared in my security-context and servllet-context. I am editing my post again.