# Spring boot ServeletInitializer and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have 2 configuration files. One is the Spring Boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
    ...
   }
```

And the Spring Security Config. it appears it isn't working. whenever I access localhost:8080 it asks for my username and password. Which I believe I configured in the `auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

but it displays invalid credentials, is there anyway to validate this?

EDIT: I am trying to convert this xml configuration to JavaConfig based but still no avail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.app.genesis.client.auth"/>

    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/index.jsp" security="none"/>

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/*" requires-channel="https"/>
        <!--TODO Add RESOURCE PATTERN checker -->
        <form-login login-page="/index.jsp" default-target-url="/dashboard"/>
        <logout />
    </http>

    <!-- Test Login values -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <!--use inMemoryUserDetailsService for faux auth -->
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

and here's my new SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private TenantDetailsService tenantUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncryptionService passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(tenantUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/index.jsp").defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard");
    }
}
```

security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.brightworks.genesis.client.auth"/>

    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/index.jsp" security="none"/>

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/*" requires-channel="https"/>
        <!--TODO Add RESOURCE PATTERN checker -->
        <form-login login-page="/index.jsp" default-target-url="/dashboard"/>
        <logout />
    </http>

    <!-- Test Login values -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <!--use inMemoryUserDetailsService for faux auth -->
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using (it works for me with 1.2.3.RELEASE)?

Comment: I am using Spring boot 1.2.3.RELEASE as well. Spring boot is using the default Spring Security Authentication

Comment: A version of the updated config also works for me. I think you have to describe what it is you do and what happens.

Comment: @DaveSyer what I am really trying to do is migrate my spring-security  configuration to Annotation based java config, however, I am failing at it. Can you help convert this xml to java based config? I've added my security-config.xml

Comment: You haven't really said what you mean by "I am failing". If you say what you are dong to test it and what goes wrong it will help.

Comment: @DaveSyer Whenever I login, my custom Authentication Manager is not being called.

Comment: Are you logging in via form login (POST to /login)? What are the request and response headers and bodies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use your own version of Authentication. You start first by disabling spring boots spring security configurations. add this on your application.properties.

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

and changed your http configuration to this.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .hasAnyRole("ROLE1","ROLE2")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/product/search", true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }
```

Match the said configurations with this login form

```
<form class="form-signin"name="f" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
            <input class="form-control form-group" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
            <a class="forgot pull-right" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
            <button name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Assuming the page login page is it "/login" the one you said the POST request to is j_spring_security_check. Hence, the loginProcessingUrl is set to

```
j_spring_security_check
```

Answer (score 3):

With auth.inMemoryAuthentication() you only define a user and its credentials.
If you want to use those, you must tell Spring Boot not to create its own defaults. Spring Boot's defaults are "user" and the password it displays in the console when you run the application.
You set your own default credentials inside application.properties file, like this:

```
security.user.name=user
security.user.password=password
management.security.role=USER
```

Comment: The basics are explained here: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security

Comment: How do I tell spring boot not to use its defaults?

Comment: You should define a configure(HttpSecurity http) method inside your class that extends the Spring Security class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, as Chapter 27 (the link above) of the Spring Boot reference documentation tells you.
The sample at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-secure, specifically the class file SampleWebSecureApplication.java together with the properties file application.properties show how you can configure form login and override, in this case, the login password.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my SecurityConfig, however, upon adding the credentials it prompted a post not supported and not allowed. What I am missing. I've also updated my question.

Comment: @user962206, one small remark though: Spring does not use /j_spring_security_check aymore. Spring uses /login instead. as default.  You may change it to what suites you best. Please refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704656/javaconfiguration-for-spring-4-0-security-3-2-j-spring-security-check).