# Spring 4 MVC/Security - Login Form not accept the correct username and password

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

Hi everyone this is a know issue and found many similar question on Stack Overflow, but the problem persist so excuse me for the banality of the question. I want to make  simple login form with a spring mvc (version 4)project and spring security (version 4), and this is done the problem is the  page show the "login failed" message even with the correct username and password. 
In the below I put the principal piece of code where I think is the problem, But if you need to see the full code is located here : https://github.com/4535992/springMVC3Diff/

**LoginController.java**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {  
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login() {
    return "login";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginerror(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "login";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(Model model) {
    return "login";
}}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
                 /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
  <listener-class> org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model + Handler mapping -->
<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.p4535992.mvc" />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <beans:property name="order" value="2" />
    <beans:property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
   <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles-definitions.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id= "messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="messages"/>
</beans:bean>
```

**security-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<!--  authentication-manager-ref="frontend"  auto-config="true"--> 
<security:http  use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/geodocuments/add" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

    <security:form-login login-page="/login" 
                         default-target-url="/geodocuments/add"
                         authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"
                         login-processing-url="/login"                                                          
                         />

    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/loginfailed"/>

</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="Admin" password="Admin123"
                            authorities="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link
        rel="stylesheet"href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>GeoDocuments</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>GeoDocuments</h1>
                    <p>Add GeoDocuments</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign in</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <spring:message
                                        code="AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials"/><br />
                                </div>
                            </c:if>                 
                            <c:url value="${request.contextPath}/login" var="loginUrl" />
                            <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
<%--                                <form action="${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="post"> --%>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="User Name"
                                                name='username' type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                                            name='password' type="password" value="">
                                    </div>

                                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                                    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"
                                        type="submit" value="Login">
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

ty in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

- change /j_spring_security_check, j_username, j_password to /login, username, password
- now when i put the incorret username and password is show the error message, but when i put the correct username-passwrod i have this exception:

  10:21:36.995 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
  org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
  at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
  10:21:36.995 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

[image]

any suggestion?

**SOLUTION**

1) Change the ROLE_ADMIN to ROLE_USER and you avoid the acces denied warning

2) Add the annotation @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')") to the controller

3) make sure the authorities="ROLE_USER" and not authorities="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"

Comment: j_spring_security_check,j_username and j_password has been deprecated. Refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704656/javaconfiguration-for-spring-4-0-security-3-2-j-spring-security-check. This is a duplicate question

Comment: thank you very much I had not seen that update in the spring security tutorial that I'm following.