# Spring 4 Security,MySQL, c3p0 connection. Login works in Spring 5, but not in Spring 4

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-security, c3p0

- **This code works in Spring 5. But my company requires Spring 4.**
- In Spring 4, login works fine with inMemoryAuthentication. But when I added jdbc logic (c3p0, MySQL dependency && add DataSource code && JDBC connection, c3p0 Connection pool .properties file); server runs, login page opens, but authentication fails (Username/Password is incorrect).
- Here is the package Structure

[image: Package Structure]

- Here is .properties file location and code.

[image: persistence-mysql.properties]

1. This is the ***Configuration class***

   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.nike.mycoolwebapp")
   @PropertySource("classpath:persistence-mysql.properties")
   public class AppConfig {

   ```
       // set up variable to hold the properties. One can use spring helper classes or use @Autowired
       @Autowired
       private Environment env; // will hold the data read from the properties file

       // set up a logger for diagnostics
       private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

       // define a bean for ViewResolver
       @Bean
       public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

           InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
           viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
           viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

           return viewResolver;
       }

       // define a bean for our security datasource
       @Bean
       public DataSource securityDataSource() {

           // create a connection pool
           ComboPooledDataSource securityDatasource  
                   = new ComboPooledDataSource();

           // set the jdbc driver
           try {
               securityDatasource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
           } catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
               // I'm wrapping this exception as runtime exception. It's unchecked and throwing that,
               // so, at least the system knows if something goes wrong, or if there's a problem
               throw new RuntimeException(exc); 
           }

           // log the connection props
           // just for sanity's sake. if it's reading from properties file
           logger.info(">>> jdbc.url= " + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
           logger.info(">>> jdbc.user= " + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
           logger.info(">>> jdbc.password= " + env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

           // set the database connection props
           securityDatasource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
           securityDatasource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
           securityDatasource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

           // set the connection pool props
           securityDatasource.setInitialPoolSize(
                   getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));

           securityDatasource.setMinPoolSize(
                   getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));

           securityDatasource.setMaxPoolSize(
                   getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));

           securityDatasource.setMaxIdleTime(
                   getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

           return securityDatasource;
       }

       // need a helper method
       // read environment property and convert to int
       private int getIntProperty(String propName) {

           String propValue = env.getProperty(propName);

           // now convert to int
           int intPropValue = Integer.parseInt(propValue);

           return intPropValue;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Here is ***Security Config***

   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   ```
   // add a reference to our security data source
   @Autowired
   private DataSource securityDataSource;

   @Autowired
   public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

       /*
         //inMemoryAuthentication deprecated in latest Spring
         auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("john").password("111").roles(
        "EMPLOYEE");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("mary").password("111").roles(
         "EMPLOYEE", "MANAGER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("susan").password("111").roles(
         "EMPLOYEE", "ADMIN");
        */

       // use jdbc aunthetication
       // tell Spring Security to use JDBC authentication with our data source
       auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);
   }

   /**
    * Configure security of web paths in application, login, logout etc
    */
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests()
               // .anyRequest().authenticated() // any request to the app must be authenticated
               // (i.e. logging in)
               .antMatchers("/").hasRole("EMPLOYEE").antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasRole("MANAGER")

                // show our custom form at the request mapping "/showMyLoginPage"
               .antMatchers("/systems/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and().formLogin().loginPage("/showLoginPage")

               .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser") // Login form should POST data to this URL for processing

               // (check username & password)
               .usernameParameter("username") // don't add this in spring 5
               .passwordParameter("password") // don't add this in spring 5

               .permitAll() // Allow everyone to see login page. No need to be logged in.
               .and().logout().permitAll().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
   }
   ```

   }
3. Here is ***MvcDispatchServletInitializer***

   public class AppSpringMvsDispatcherServlerInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   ```
   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
       return new Class[] {AppConfig.class};
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
       return new String[] {"/"};
   }
   ```

   }
4. Here is ***SecurityWebApplicationInitializer***

   public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

   }
5. Here is ***pom.xml***

   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       4.0.0

   ```
   <groupId>com.nike.mycoolwebapp</groupId>
   <artifactId>mycoolwebapp</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <name>mycoolwebapp</name>

   <properties>
       <springframework.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
       <springsecurity.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>

       <c3po.version>0.9.5.2</c3po.version>

       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>

       <!-- Spring MVC support -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
           <version>${springframework.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Spring Security -->
       <!-- spring-security-web and spring-security-config -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
           <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
       </dependency>   

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
           <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
       </dependency>   

       <!-- Add Spring Security Taglibs support -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
           <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Add MySQL support -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>8.0.18</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Add c3p0 support -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
           <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
           <version>${c3po.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Servlet, JSP and JSTL support -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
           <version>1.2</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- to compensate for java 9+ not including jaxb -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
           <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.1</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <!-- TO DO: Add support for Maven WAR Plugin -->
   <build>
       <finalName>mycoolwebapp</finalName>

       <pluginManagement>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <!-- Add Maven coordinates (GAV) for: maven-war-plugin -->
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.2.0</version>                    
               </plugin>                       
           </plugins>
       </pluginManagement>
   </build>
   ```
6. Here is ***AppController***

   @Controller
   public class AppController {

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showHome() {
       return "home";
   }

   // add a request mapping for /leaders
   @RequestMapping(value = "/leaders", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showLeader() {
       return "leaders";
   }

   // add a request mapping for /systems
   @RequestMapping(value = "/systems", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showAdmin() {
       return "systems";
   }
   ```

   }
7. Here is the ***Login Controller***.

   @Controller
   public class LoginController {

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/showLoginPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showLoginPage() {
       return "fancy-login";
   }

   // add a request mapping for /access-denied
   @RequestMapping(value = "/access-denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showAccessDenied() {
       return "access-denied";
   }
   ```

   }
8. Here are ***MySQL tables***

[image: Authorities]

[image: Roles]

Comment: Give a look to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704656/javaconfiguration-for-spring-4-0-security-3-2-j-spring-security-check

Answer (score 0):

- Remove {noop} from the database. {noop} or {bcrypt} is in Spring 5.